# My particles are vanishing after 250 frames, not sure whats going on. (Lifetime is set to 350)

Tags: particles

Not sure whats going on with my particles here, they are vanishing after 250 frames : [image]

My particle settings: [image]

Sadly google search results are a bit tough to filter through for anything blender. Hopefully one of you know what the deal is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you modify any of the settings for the second time? Like did first you set lifetime to 250 and later to 350? It that's the case, you should set current frame to 0 and replay it with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

Another possibility is the clipping: set the End value of clipping to a higher value or start value to a lower value (you can tab the panel with shortcut <kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: You may need to rephrase this with proper terminology, (lifetime start and lifetime end) but you've got the right idea for an answer.

Comment: It's only 'start' and 'end', and only 'lifetime', according to the image, right? :)

Comment: That did the trick. Alt A. What exactly does that do?

Comment: Alt A will do the simulation again. Better results if done at frame 0